# Convolutional Network for Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network with Keras at recognizing tags for Stack Exchange questions about cooking.

The i-th question element of my data-set is like this:

```
id                                                         2
title                    How should I cook bacon in an oven?
content    <p>I've heard of people cooking bacon in an ov...
tags                                 oven cooking-time bacon
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

I have removed tags with BeautifulSoup and removed punctuation too.
Since questions' content are very big I have decided to focus on titles. 
I have used sklearn CountVectorizer to vectorize words in titles. However they were more than 8000 words (excluding stop words). So I decided apply a part of speech tagging and retrieve only Nouns and Gerunds.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
titles = dataframes['cooking']['title']
pos_titles = []
for i,title in enumerate(titles):
    pos = []
    pt_titl = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(title))
    for pt in pt_titl:
        if pt[1]=='NN' or pt[1]=='NNS' or pt[1]=='VBG':# or pt[1]=='VBP' or pt[1]=='VBS':
            pos.append(pt[0])
    pos_titles.append(" ".join(pos))
```

This represents my input vector. I have vectorized tags too and extract dense matrixes for both input and tags.

```
tags = [" ".join(x) for x in dataframes['cooking']['tags']]
Xd = X.todense()

Y = vectorizer.fit_transform(tags)
Yd = Y.todense()
```

Split data into train and validation set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xd, Yd, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Now I am trying to train a Conv1D network

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,Conv1D, Embedding,GlobalMaxPooling1D,Dropout,MaxPooling1D

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(Xd.shape[1],
                    128,
                    input_length=Xd.shape[1]))
model.add(Conv1D(32,5,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(100,stride=50))
model.add(Conv1D(32,5,activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(Yd.shape[1], activation ='softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32,verbose=1)
```

But it gets stucked on a very low accuracy and it shows a barely increasing loss along the epochs

```
Epoch 1/10
10320/10320 [==============================] - 401s - loss: 15.8098 - acc: 0.0604   
Epoch 2/10
10320/10320 [==============================] - 339s - loss: 15.5671 - acc: 0.0577   
Epoch 3/10
10320/10320 [==============================] - 314s - loss: 15.5509 - acc: 0.0578   
Epoch 4/10
10320/10320 [==============================] - 34953s - loss: 15.5493 - acc: 0.0578  
Epoch 5/10
10320/10320 [==============================] - 323s - loss: 15.5587 - acc: 0.0578   
Epoch 6/10
 6272/10320 [=================>............] - ETA: 133s - loss: 15.6005 - acc: 0.0550
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function value is not going into right direction. This means your model is not able to capture features it needs to focus on. There are 2 ways you can try

1. Change your model. I'll suggest first pick up some widely used model for text classification. Then experiment with it towards better accuracy
2. Although your input representation makes sense, you can try with some specialized sentence-to-vectors models like [skip-thought](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06726) (one implementation [here](https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts))

Comment: You can reduce your features by stemming your text. A further reduction can be achieved by dealing with words such as "woooooooow" which suppose to be "wow" or "loooooooooove" which refers to"love". Also I hope you lower all the text, this will unite "LOVE" and "love" as same feature.